# Android Studio 3.0.1 Image Asset

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm having trouble configuring my launcher icon using Launcher Icons (Adaptive and Legacy). I created an already round PNG icon as an example.

[image]

I want it to appear just like that but the background layer cannot be set to transparent.

[image]

Is it possible remove the background layer? What is the recommended way?

Comment: You need to provide a PNG icon with a bigger resolution, at least 512x512. And the background layer is usually set with white colour, because it is needed to create parallax effects with the main icon

Comment: @MatPag I noticed that after pressing Finish, it created icons for foreground, round, and normal one. What should I use here for android:icon?

Comment: Read [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_adaptive.html)

Comment: @MatPag oh yes, I forgot that link. Anyways, thanks a lot.